# How to turn this simple Spark Streaming code into a Multi threaded one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am learning Kafka in Scala. The attached code is just a word count implementation using Kafka and Spark Streaming. 
How do I have a separate consumer execution per partition whilst streaming? Please help!

Here is my code:

```
class ConsumerM(topics: String, bootstrap_server: String, group_name: String) {

  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafkaWordCount")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.executor.memory","1g")

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

  val topicsSet = topics.split(",")

  val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> bootstrap_server,
    ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> group_name,
    ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "auto.offset.reset" ->"earliest")


  val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))


  val lines = messages.map(_.value)
  val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
  val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
  wordCounts.print()

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

Comment: You mean you want each partition to be read by separate executor? That's the default behavior if I m not wrong.

Comment: I want a separate consumer for every partition .. and then aggregating results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input topic has multiple partitions, then additionally setting `local[*]` means you'll have one Spark executor per CPU core, and at least one partition can be consumed by each